# JS: как добавить к ключу объекта счётчик цикла?

Tags: javascript, циклы, объекты, счетчики

Есть условный объект вида:

```
let obj = {
    smallNews: {
        title1: "Заголовок 1",
        title2: "Заголовок 2",
        title3: "Заголовок 3",
        title4: "Заголовок 4",
    }
}
```

Когда я обращаюсь напрямую к какому-то из ключей, то могу вывести его значение:

```
console.log(obj.smallNews.title2) // Заголовок 2
```

А как вывести все значения в обычном цикле? Т.е. как добавить в цикле к ключу `title` значение счётчика?

Сейчас делаю так: сначала формирую строку, а потом с помощью `eval` получаю значение. Но, имхо, это не самый удачный способ. Можно ли сделать иначе?

```js
let obj = {
    smallNews: {
        title1: "Заголовок 1",
        title2: "Заголовок 2",
        title3: "Заголовок 3",
        title4: "Заголовок 4",
    }
}

for (let i = 1; i<= 4; i++) {
  let str = 'obj.smallNews.title'+i;
    console.log(eval(str));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
    smallNews: {
        title1: "Заголовок 1",
        title2: "Заголовок 2",
        title3: "Заголовок 3",
        title4: "Заголовок 4",
    }
}

for (const key in obj.smallNews)
{
    console.log(obj.smallNews[key]);
}
```

---

Или же:

```js
let obj = {
    smallNews: {
        title1: "Заголовок 1",
        title2: "Заголовок 2",
        title3: "Заголовок 3",
        title4: "Заголовок 4",
    }
}

Object.values(obj.smallNews).forEach((title) =>
{
  console.log(title);
});
```

---

Но у меня вопрос, почему бы не использовать изначально массив?

```js
let obj = {
    smallNews: [
        "Заголовок 1",
        "Заголовок 2",
        "Заголовок 3",
        "Заголовок 4",
    ]
};

obj.smallNews.forEach((title) =>
{
  console.log(title);
});
```

---

После комментария:

```js
let obj = {
    smallNews: {
        title1: "Заголовок 1",
        title2: "Заголовок 2",
        title3: "Заголовок 3",
        title4: "Заголовок 4",
    }
}

for (let i = 1; i<= 4; i++) {
    console.log(obj.smallNews['title' +i]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это не то, что мне надо. Вопрос не в том, как правильно обойти объект и получить значения ключей. Задача - добавить к ключу счётчик цикла. Т.е. как соединить с цифрой, чтобы получился валидный ключ

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: Да, вот это то, что надо! Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно вывести в виде массива

```
let a = []
for ( i in obj.smallNews) {
    a.push(obj.smallNews[i])
    console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> А как вывести все значения в обычном цикле?

Если задача именно в этом, то ключи в принципе не требуются (в том смысле, что незачем их имена вычислять) - можно просто получить значения соотв. методом:

```js
const obj = {
  smallNews: {
    title1: "Заголовок 1",
    title2: "Заголовок 2",
    title3: "Заголовок 3",
    title4: "Заголовок 4",
  },
};

for (const value of Object.values(obj.smallNews))
  console.log(value);
```

---

То есть, я конечно вижу и понимаю о чем задан вопрос - по сути, он о способе решения задачи "вычислить имена ключей объекта"... но возможно, что сама задача поставлена неправильно/неоптимально. Ведь если подумать, то вычисление ключей таким образом, создает ряд потенциальных проблем:

- вероятность ошибиться в ожидании наличия указанных ключей (получения `undefined`)
- вероятность обратиться к прототипному свойству объекта, вместо собственного
- затрудненная отладка, как из-за первых двух пунктов, так и из-за всяких других мелочей (например, причины возможного вывода в консоли а-ля "не удалось получить свойство значения undefined" несколько малоочевидны, и надо код открывать чтобы найти место с тем самым циклом)
- банально пустая трата ресурсов на строковые операции (это совсем не критично когда лишь 4 ключа, но в циклах по длинным массивам толстых объектов, да с вложенностью - может опечалить).

Третий пункт спорный, но остальные вполне реальны, имхо.
Само по себе, вычисление ключей это не совсем зло... точнее, это *зло которое бывает необходимым*. Вот есть ли в нем необходимость - именно то, о чем написан данный ответ, то о чем я призываю задумываться (т.к. сам временами напрасно усложняю решения  ).